# Change the default behaviour of edit text in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

So I have make a bottom sheet drawer inside it i have a recycler view which have a set of item in list manner. so every item on click opens and have a chat box in it. so the problem here is i have make a custom editText for that but default property of edittext is it only take in focus a single line not all. so can you provide me some idea how can make all the edittext above the keyboard not a single line whenever i open it

solution i have used a --> used windowSoftInput as adjustPan , adjustResize , change the focus of edittext as well as applied focus listener on edittext , change properties of scroll view to focusonTouch listener . so can you provide me how can i make my edittext to go up whenever focus goes on it as it is multiline

Answer (score 0):

You can change your main bottom sheet layout with nested scroll view it should work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).